# How to speed up the performance of QGIS when updating a data?

Tags: postgresql, qgis

I am using QGIS 2.18.9 and Postgresql with PGadmin 4 database. What am I going to do to speed up the performance in QGIS? because evertime I do an insert or update in QGIS the performance is slow. For example, I'm going to change a data or put some data in one of my layers, and everytime I save it, it took an hour. I already did the indexing, I put index in my database but it did'nt help. What am I going to do?

here is the trigger for my line layer

```
begin

update lines l
set frompole = p.polecode
from qgispoles p 
where concat(p.x,p.y)= concat (l.x1,l.y1);

update lines l
set topole = p.polecode
from qgispoles p
where concat (p.x,p.y) = concat (l.x2,l.y2) ;

update lines 
set feeder = left(topole,4);

update lines
set prilineid = case when lineserved ILIKE '%Phase%' then 
concat('Pri_',count_line) else null end;

update lines
set seclineid = case when dtid ILIKE '%_%' then concat (dtid,'_',gid) else 
null 
end;

update lines 
set sectype=case when secphasing <>'None' then 'ACSR' else '' end,
  secsize=case when secphasing<>'None' then '2' else null end,
  secunit=case when secphasing<>'None' then 'AWG' else '' end,
  secstrand=case when secphasing<>'None' then '6/1' else '' end,
  phatype=case when priphasing ilike '%A%' then 'ACSR' else '' end,
phasize=case when priphasing ilike '%A%' then '2/0' else '' end,
phaunit=case when priphasing ilike '%A%' then 'AWG' else '' end,
phastrand=case when priphasing ilike '%A%' then '6/1' else '' end,
phbtype=case when priphasing ilike '%B%' then 'ACSR' else '' end,
phbsize=case when priphasing ilike '%B%' then '2/0' else '' end,
phbunit=case when priphasing ilike '%B%' then 'AWG' else '' end,
phbstrand=case when priphasing ilike '%B%' then '6/1' else '' end,
phctype=case when priphasing ilike '%C%' then 'ACSR' else '' end,
phcsize=case when priphasing ilike '%C%' then '2/0' else '' end,
phcunit=case when priphasing ilike '%C%' then 'AWG' else '' end,
phcstrand=case when priphasing ilike '%C%' then '6/1' else '' end;

update lines
 set pritype='ACSR', prisize='2/0', priunit='AWG', pristrand='6/1'
 where lineserved ILIKE '%Phase%';

return new;
end;
```

Comment: Can you add an example query you executed? Also, is the performance also bad on a small table, like with fewer rows or with fewer columns? Maybe you can create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to help us see the problem

Comment: I've tried working with small table, and the performance was not bad. But when I tried my work in a Bigger table with lots of data the performance was very slow, It took almost an Hour every update that I make. :(

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it's not the `UPDATE` that is slow, it's selecting the rows to update. I'll walk you through the code and show where things are slower than they need to be.

Firstly, if you were to change all updates to `SELECT`, you would still have a very slow sequence, because in some cases, you're literally updating every row you have. Let's make that easier if possible.

```sql
begin

update lines l
set frompole = p.polecode
from qgispoles p 
where concat(p.x,p.y)= concat (l.x1,l.y1);

update lines l
set topole = p.polecode
from qgispoles p
where concat (p.x,p.y) = concat (l.x2,l.y2) ;
```

In these two update statements, you use `concat(...) = concat(...)`. This makes the compiler not know what to expect, so it cannot be smart about what to ignore. If you change this to `WHERE p.x = l.x2 AND p.y = l.y2`, you should get exactly the same result, but hopefully a little bit faster.

```sql
update lines 
set feeder = left(topole,4);

update lines
set prilineid = case when lineserved ILIKE '%Phase%' then 
concat('Pri_',count_line) else null end;

update lines
set seclineid = case when dtid ILIKE '%_%' then concat (dtid,'_',gid) else 
null 
end;
```

This is where the real pain happens. You're updating *all* lines three times! These are obviously calculated fields, so there is no pain in overwriting them, except for the computational overhead. Why do it like this if you're only updating a few lines? I see a couple of solutions:

1. Set these fields inside the other queries. Did you know you can use multiple `SET`s? `UPDATE lines l SET topole = p.polecode, feeder = left(p.polecode 4)...` should take care of one of them, immediately;
2. Another possibility is to set a boolean flag `needs_updating`: `UPDATE lines l SET topole = p.polecode, needs_updating=TRUE ...`, followed by `UPDATE lines  SET feeder = left(topole,4) WHERE needs_updating=TRUE` means you don't need to traverse the entire table and update every single row. And when you're done, set `needs_updating` to false.

The only drawback of the second solution is if you have multiple processes writing at the same time, one could set `NEEDS_UPDATING` to false when done, while the other was still busy, but that depends entirely on your setup and is probably not a big deal in your case.

```sql
update lines 
set sectype=case when secphasing <>'None' then 'ACSR' else '' end,
  secsize=case when secphasing<>'None' then '2' else null end,
  secunit=case when secphasing<>'None' then 'AWG' else '' end,
  secstrand=case when secphasing<>'None' then '6/1' else '' end,
  phatype=case when priphasing ilike '%A%' then 'ACSR' else '' end,
phasize=case when priphasing ilike '%A%' then '2/0' else '' end,
phaunit=case when priphasing ilike '%A%' then 'AWG' else '' end,
phastrand=case when priphasing ilike '%A%' then '6/1' else '' end,
phbtype=case when priphasing ilike '%B%' then 'ACSR' else '' end,
phbsize=case when priphasing ilike '%B%' then '2/0' else '' end,
phbunit=case when priphasing ilike '%B%' then 'AWG' else '' end,
phbstrand=case when priphasing ilike '%B%' then '6/1' else '' end,
phctype=case when priphasing ilike '%C%' then 'ACSR' else '' end,
phcsize=case when priphasing ilike '%C%' then '2/0' else '' end,
phcunit=case when priphasing ilike '%C%' then 'AWG' else '' end,
phcstrand=case when priphasing ilike '%C%' then '6/1' else '' end;

update lines
 set pritype='ACSR', prisize='2/0', priunit='AWG', pristrand='6/1'
 where lineserved ILIKE '%Phase%';

return new;
end;
```

Here, you're doing a lot of processing of all the rows again. Use the same methods as above to limit the scope, that should help a lot.

Comment: Thank You sir, This helps a lot. :)